# Regarding documentation for renewing US visit visa in Canada

Tags: b1-b2-visas, applications, pakistani-citizens

Hi I am on visit visa in Canada. My us visit visa is valid till feb 2. I have to travel to USA on feb end . I cannot travel before feb 2 because I am sick. Please let me know if I can apply to renew my us visa from here in Canada and what documents do I need for the application. I am originally from Pakistan doing business in Oman.

Comment: Have you been in the US in the last two weeks?

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same as applying from Pakistan. The only documents that you need is a valid passport and a DS160 form. The consular officer will very likely ask why you're applying from Canada. USA visa consulars rarely ask for supporting documents but it would make sense to carry what you can.

Answer (score 0):

Information about the required documentation is available here https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html#documentation In addition, in case the consular officer asks, you should be prepared to provide additional documents to show you qualify for the visa and to demonstrate the purpose of your trip, your I ntent to depart the USA after your trip, and/or your ability to pay all costs of the trip.